# ubuntu 20.10, Gnome wayland, apps don't scale

Tags: gnome, scaling, hdpi

ubuntu 20.10, Gnome wayland , apps don't scale.

I set one monitor to scale 200% (i'd prefer 150%, but i don't see that option :/)
'ubuntu' apps, like settings or terminal comply with that setting, but most of others:
Intellij IDEA, Chrome, Slack, VS Code, Firefox or GIMP
don't scale at all, or sometimes they stay 200% all the time.
How to improve it ? I tried on 'standard' Ubuntu (on X11?) with fractional scaling, it was ok, but on i7-10510 i felt like system works on 15fps....

Answer (score 2):

**Concerning Firefox:**

You need to set the environment variable `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1`.
You can do this in two ways:

1. into your terminal type `export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1`
2. edit the file /etc/environment and add the line `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1`

[Learn more about environment variables here.](https://linoxide.com/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/)

**Concerning other applications:** (Not 100% sure this is the correct explanation!)

They are probably made for X11 and won't work perfectly under wayland. Either you need to find a version of the program made for Wayland or hope for better X11 support under Wayland in the future.